# pandoc document conversion failed with error 43 : pdflatex: The memory dump file could not be found

Tags: rstudio, pandoc

RStudio : 0.98.994
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate Edition, 64-bit Service Pack 1
MiKTeX: 2.9.4503

Hi,

I get the following error when I try to knit a PDF document.

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9)
pdflatex: The memory dump file could not be found.
pdflatex: Data: pdflatex.fmt

Answer (score 27):

I also tried **devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')** but was still getting an error when I added **'fig.align='center'** to a ggplot2 plot in my document. It would work as HTML, but not as PDF.

After seeing *isomorphismes*'s post I clicked on the gear symbol next to the **knit PDF** button, then under the advanced tab I changed the LaTeX Engine to **xelatex**. After that I no longer received the error message and my PDF document was created without problems.

Thank you.

Comment: Changing the LaTeX Engine to xelatex worked for me when the error was being caused by a figure alignment chunk option.

Comment: I had the same problem and changed the engine to **lualatex** using **xelatex** resulted in an error about the missing *fontconfig* file.

Answer (score 24):

I found the answer here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/tufte_handout_format.html#comment-1582377678

The problem is that you need to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputnc}` to the preamble of the `tufte-handout.tex` file in the rmarkdown package.

This was fixed here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/484d5b8e903e0e0c75c82f707efa35f9fd9a52b0

To update your rmarkdown package, you can use directly in the RStudio command line

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, a full service solution which worked for me.

Comment: This really helped me. All I did was to run the code     devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown"). And now it works. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 11):

None of the above worked for me when knitting to PDF (and I wanted to keep the scientific notation). The problem was that latex code was generated that included "\times" without the necessary bracketing by $. In the markdown I simply bracketed the inline R code with $'s, like so:

```
$p = `r signif(cor.HF$p.value, 2)`$
```

Voila!

Answer (score 8):

happy to share with you my solution.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "-----"
date: "21/6/2017"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Comment: while the other solutions didn't work for me, this did

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it in my case. I experienced that error when generate PDF from Rmd if I added float values into a text that R tried to display as a scientific notation. For example, instead of "520274.72" it tried to add text "5.2027472 e10-5" which leads to latex code \textbf{5.2027472\times 10\^{}{5}} that was not compiling. I fixed it by wrapping it with **format(....,scientific=FALSE)**.

replace
`r round(txn_pd,2)`

with
`r format(round(txn_pd,2),scientific=FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and `devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')` didn't work for me. I needed to

```
rmarkdown::render('in.md',

      output_format=pdf_document(latex_engine='xelatex')

      )
```

with the novel command (use `xelatex`) on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem while I was trying to add an in-line r code `r test1$p.value`, which is a very small p-value from *t test*. The error information is as following:

```
> ! Missing $ inserted.  
>  <inserted text>  
>            $  
>l.147   9.0044314\times  
>
>pandoc: Error producing PDF
>Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>Execution halted
```

I think the problem is the **pdflatex** engine has a trouble in displaying the small p-value in exponential notation.
I solved the problem by clicking on the gear symbol next to the **knit** button, then under **output options, advanced tab** I changed the LaTeX Engine to **lualatex**, or you can just report the p-value as *p < 0.001*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using inline values from your R code which are in the scientific format (too small or too big), format them like:

replace `r x`

with `r format(x, digits=n)` where n is whatever.

Answer (score 1):

for me it was because on my headers I was putting + signs. For example `gene + treatment.` This errors but when I removed it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved simply by editing the author field in:

```html
---
title: "Document Title"
author: '-----'
date: "21-03-2017"
output: pdf_document
---
```

the default '-----' would yield the error, but replacing it with anything (for example 'Juan') solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and already solved it. I didn't use any code as other people did in their posts.
I will assume that you have installed all these basic stuff: R, RStudio, the rmarkdown package, the knitr package, and the MikTex basic installation (I know this is very basic, but I want those first timers know that you need these stuff to make this happen).
If you run into this problem, go to R GUI, upgrade the rmarkdown package and it should work then. Note that if you change the LaTeX Engine to xelatex as the poster of the highest vote did, it may not work for you, at least it did not for me. I leave my latex engine as it is (pdflatex).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My solution was to remove the "leading" period in the YAML title argument:

Does not work:

```
---  
title: “1. Title”  
output: pdf_document  
---
```

> output file: example.knit.md
>
> ! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.  
>                   \par  l.79 \end{enumerate}}
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF Error: pandoc document conversion failed
>   with error 43 Execution halted

Works:

```
---
title: “1 Title”
output: pdf_document
---
```

Answer (score 0):

I did try to use the xelatex engine but still, I got the error that xetex.def is not found. This is another to work around.

```
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

Then open .tex file in your TEX editor and build pdf as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. In my case, the error occurred because of putting a percentage inside the $ sign.
Like this,

> $95%$, I removed the % sign, and everything worked fine.