# Rmarkdown error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to compile a RMarkdown code but I'm getting the following error:

```
! Misplaced \crcr.
\LT@echunk ->\crcr 
                   \LT@save@row \cr \egroup \global \setbox \@ne \lastbox \u...
l.374 NA NA NA NA NA NA \endfirsthead

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Erro: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Além disso: Warning message:
execução do comando '"C:/Users/araujoic/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Script_GerarRelatorio_Isabella.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output Script_GerarRelatorio_Isabella.pdf --template "C:\Users\araujoic\Documents\R\R-3.3.2\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --include-in-header "C:\Users\araujoic\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpakSZ3U\file14746f4c7a09"' teve status 43 
Execução interrompida
```

Can someone help me? The code runs with no problems on other computers.

Thanks!

Comment: If it runs successfully on other computers, I would start by checking that all of the computers have the same LaTeX packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a solution here: [pandoc document conversion failed with error 43 : pdflatex: The memory dump file could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856362/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-43-pdflatex-the-memory-dump-file)

Bottom line is, try this: devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')